# How to open a new window while clicking on a link using java

Tags: java, selenium, window, webdriver

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).isDisplayed() != True){
    // if clicked in the above condition is True then it has to be opened in a new window
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).click();
}

else {
    System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
```

Comment: If the element has click action, and when we click on that element click automatically open a new window.

Answer (score 4):

You can open link in new window using below code :

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your link xpath"));
Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);
newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Generally we press SHIFT key and click using mouse to open link in new window , I did same thing here via code in selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet; just **replace the locator with what you want**, and it should work:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='हिन्दी']"))).contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

**The above snippet navigates to Google site, then right clicks on the concerned link *"हिन्दी"* in this case, and uses the down key twice to reach the option of "Open link in a new window" and then sends "Enter" key to click on it, which then opens a new window.**

**NOTE:-** **This works fine in Firefox and Chrome. In case of Internet Explorer, you might have to add one extra `sendKeys(keys.DOWN)`** and it should be good because the **option for "Open link in a new window" comes in the third place**. Please check the snippet change for the same, below:

```
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='हिन्दी']"))).contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is injecting JS to set the target attribute on a link:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("my link"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "return arguments[0].target='_blank'";
Object result = js.executeScript(script, link);
link.click();
```

The result line can probably be ignored but I found this being more reliable.

---

By the way:

1) Never compare to true or false. Instead of

```
    if (condition != true)
```

write

```
    if (! condition)
```

2) Do not look up the same element every time. Look for it once and save the reference.

3) You can't click a link that is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
//opens the browser
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
//create object for Actions class and pass driver value     
  Actions ac=new Actions(driver);
//identify the WebElement
  WebElement signUpLink=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up"));
```

ac.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(signUpLink).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);

//The above code will help to open the link in new tab

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).