# switch to new window after clicking on the hyperlink using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone help me how to switch to new window after clicking on a hyperlink using selenium while doing automation . I have tried the following code but my test case is failing :

```
public void openView(){

        final WebElement visa=driver.findElement(By.id("pageContainer"));   
        timeOut(10000);
        final List<WebElement> images=visa.findElements(By.className("nametag"));
        String handlewindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        images.get(0).findElement(By.className("info")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();;
```

Comment: What do you mean test case is failing?? in which line its failing?? and what is the exception??

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603309/how-to-open-a-new-window-while-clicking-on-a-link-using-java) may help you out to get your answer.

Comment: You said in a comment below that you're actually referring to a new tab, not a new window. Would you mind updating the question?

Comment: @Anita can you please point out your steps what you are trying to do. From your question I can guess your steps like these: 1. You have one tab open in your browser? 2. Then from that tab you are trying to click a link? 3. Then you are trying to create a new Tab and trying to switch to that new Tab??

Answer (score 0):

This what we're using (Java):

```
public void switchToLatestPopupWindow()
{
    Iterator<String> handleIterator = this.driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
    while (handleIterator.hasNext())
    {
        String handle = handleIterator.next();
        if (!handleIterator.hasNext())
        {
            this.driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        }
    }
}

public void resetToMainWindow()
{
    Iterator<String> handleIterator = this.driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
    String parentHandle = null;
    while (handleIterator.hasNext())
    {
        String handle = handleIterator.next();
        if (parentHandle == null)
        {
            parentHandle = handle;
        } else if (!parentHandle.equals(handle))
        {
            this.driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            this.driver.close();
        }
    }
    this.driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last line of code:

```
images.get(0).findElement(By.className("info")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click()
```

opens a new window, you are fetching the window handle of the parent window itself before the child window opens after click().

Secondly, here is the code for switching to a child window:

```
String handlewindow = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];
driver.switchTo().window(handlewindow);
```

The explanation is that driver.getWindowHandles() returns a Set of all open windows handles. Convert the Set to array and fetch the element at index 1 as child window is at 1, parent window is at 0.

Comment: Hi @ChandrachudNanduri i tried what you said but it's opening in the same tab .Can you tell me how to make it open in a new tab .Like a separate tab should be open for it.

Comment: the requirement is not clear ... 
I assumed when you click on a link, it automatically opens in a new window and you wanted help in switching to the new window. The answer I gave does that.

Comment: No i not's opening in another tab it's opening in same window.

Comment: Use this code picked up from another thread on Stackoverflow ...  

`WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("<your id>"));`  
`Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);`  `newwin.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();`

Comment: this not using switchTo() function

Comment: check my latest answer ... try that ... if it doesn't work let me know ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code picked up from another thread on Stackoverflow ...

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("<your link text>")); 
Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);
newwin.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)‌​.build().perform();
```

I checked this and it opens the link in a new tab. Then use this code to switch to the new tab ...

```
String handlewindow = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];
driver.switchTo().window(handlewindow);
```

Comment: its still opening in the same tab only not a separate one :(

Comment: i checked the code in my eclipse and it opened in a new tab ... I am not sure what is happening at your end

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop we need to check if the current window handle is not equal to the one which is fetched by the loop

```
String handlewindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    if (! handlewindow.equals (winHandle))
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Actions ac  = Actions(driverObj);
    String parentHandle = driverObj.getWindowHandle();
    WebElement we = driverObj.findElement(By.xpath("here is your xpath"));
    ac.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(we).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    String currentHandle ="";
    Set<String> win  = ts.getDriver().getWindowHandles();   

    Iterator<String> it =  win.iterator();
    if(win.size() > 1){
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String handle = it.next();
            if (!handle.equalsIgnoreCase(parentHandle)){
                ts.getDriver().switchTo().window(handle);
                currentHandle = handle;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Unable to switch");
    }
```

Using above code you can open any link in new tab..

Answer (score 0):

For switching between tabs you can use this methods:

```
    public void switchToNextTab() {
        ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
    }

    public void switchToPreviousTab() {
        ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(0));
    }
```